# Can I open a new tab to left of the current tab?

Tags: vim, tabs, customization

Issuing `:tabnew somefile` will open `somefile` in a new tab to the *right* of the current tab. Can I somehow get Vim to open a tab to the *left* of the current tab?

**Update**: The suggested answers do allow me to open a new tab left, but they break file name auto completion, which is a no-go.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To utilize the behavior @romainl described without having to resort to knowing current tab page number use the following command:

```
command -nargs=* -bar Tabnew :execute (tabpagenr()-1).'tabnew '.<q-args>
```

. Note: it is perfectly save to use `0tabnew`: this does what intended and makes new tab the first one, even though there is no tab page that has number below 1.

If you are sure you never use this command with `++opt` or `+cmd` you can use `-complete=file` just after `-bar`. Note: besides its name it is *not* a completion option because it as well does filename expansion (and shows errors in case `-nargs=1` and globs expanded in too many filenames). Unfortunately this behavior is not even mentioned in documentation.

Answer (score 22):

Since [Vim 7.4.530 (2014)](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/b96a7f325c9047d6a65424d40e493d3e0eff26b5), you can use negative values for `[count]` in `:[count]tabnew` to open tabs. To open a tab directly to the left of the current tab, use:

```
:-1tabnew
```

Documentation: https://vimhelp.appspot.com/tabpage.txt.html#:tabnew

```
:[count]tabe[dit]                               :tabe :tabedit :tabnew
:[count]tabnew
                Open a new tab page with an empty window, after the current
                tab page.  If [count] is given the new tab page appears after
                the tab page [count] otherwise the new tab page will appear
                after the current one. 
                    :tabnew     " opens tabpage after the current one
                    :.tabnew    " as above
                    :+tabnew    " opens tabpage after the next tab page
                                " note: it is one further than :tabnew
                    :-tabnew    " opens tabpage before the current one
                    :0tabnew    " opens tabpage before the first one
                    :$tabnew    " opens tabpage after the last one
```

Similar functionality is also available for `:tabclose`, `:tabonly`, `:tabmove`, see the commit linked above. If this does not work, use `:version` to check if your Vim is up-to-date and/or use `:help tabnew` to check whether the documentation looks like the one cited here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `[count]`. Supposing you are at tab #4, `:3tabnew` creates a new tab on the left of the current tab.

Keep in mind, though, that tabs are *always* created to the right of the current tab or tab #`[count]`. `:3tabnew` effectively means "create a new tab *after* tab #3".

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own command to do this

```
:command -nargs=1 TabnewBefore exec "tabnew <args>" | exec "tabmove -1"
```

Then to use it

```
:TabnewBefore somefile
```

If you want it to be the default 'tabnew' bahaviour you can do

```
:ca tabne TabnewBefore
```

Now if you type `tabne` and press space on the command line it does what you want, if you want the original behaviour type the full command `tabnew`

You can put these definitions into your .vimrc file for future use

Comment: Now try `TabnewBefore "` and `TabnewBefore \<C-a>` compared to `tabnew "` and `tabnew \<C-a>`. There is a perfect reason for using `-bar` and `<q-args>`.

Comment: I have a shortcut to "type" `:tabnew ` anyway, so this sounds like precisely the right thing.

Comment: @bitmask What I am talking about is that this command is unable to reproduce original `tabnew` behavior. By the way, I have not mentioned, but it does not allow using `:tabnew` without arguments.

Comment: I get `E488: Trailing characters: tabmove -1` when using the command. Any idea what that means?

Comment: @bitmask I am likely able to explain this if you show how did you call it. Currently no idea how can you get exactly this error, utilizing the problems I reported earlier should result in other errors.

Comment: @ZyX: Like described in the original answer (first two snippets). But don't mind, I already used your suggestion.

Comment: @bitmask Strange. Those snippets work perfectly. What would not work is trying to do something non-trivial like opening file with a quote in a new tab with this command.

Comment: @ZyX: Good points - my answer forces the user to use tabnew in a particular way (I basically thought, "how would I do that manually?  Open the tab then move it afterwards.  OK, I'll have a command do that."), yours is better since it preserves the user's choice of how to use the tabnew command.